# ACRA, overridden send is custom ReportSender never called

Tags: android, acra

I recently upgraded ACRA to version 4.5.0 and the send method in my custom ReportSender is no longer getting called.

By look at the logs, it looks like it is attempting to upload the crash report to Google Docs.

I have included some of our code below.

***Custom ReportSender:***

```java
public class AcraPassportSender implements ReportSender {
    ...
    public AcraPassportSender(int versionCode, boolean isStoreVersion){
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void send(CrashReportData report) throws ReportSenderException {
        PLog.i(TAG, "Attempting to create and upload a bug report");
    ...
    }
}
```

***Application Class:***

```java
@ReportsCrashes(formKey="")
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ACRA.init(this);
        AcraPassportSender acsender = new AcraPassportSender(version, isStoreVersion);
        ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender(acsender);
    }
}
```

The logs show ACRA getting initialized.  This worked before I upgraded ACRA.  Any ideas of what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the following sentence on the [website of ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/):

> Since the recent update of Google Forms by Google, the usage of Google
>   Docs as a storage engine for ACRA reports is now deprecated.

As far as I know, Google Forms was default method of crash reporting in ACRA. You can look at [ACRA project on GitHub](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and try to use different reporting method than Google Forms.

Moreover, I recommend you to use tools like [Crashlytics](https://get.fabric.io/crashlytics), which are better than ACRA, allows you to collect crash reports and monitor your applications. Note that Crashlytics were acquired by Twitter and now they're available under [fabric.io](https://get.fabric.io/) domain. You can also use paid tools like [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com/) or create your own reporting solution.

Comment: Yes, I created a custom ReportSender: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#implementing-your-own-sender  However, the logs show a post to Google Docs when it should be using this custom behavior.

Comment: If you did it this way, I think you should use HttpSender, define your custom url and prepare your server to collect crash data or use EmailIntentSender and send crashes to specified email via intent. I guess GoogleFormSender may be outdated or library behaves in a different way than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of ACRA is 4.6.2. I would suggest upgrading to that.

GoogleFormSender was removed in 4.6.0. Other than that it is hard to know wwhat is goinf on as you have not posted the code for your Sender and you have not posted your logcat.

I suggest upgrading to 4.6.2 first and then reassessing.